# How to distinguish between a linear region and a quadratic region

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to write a vba code that would be able to take in 2 arrays of x and y points which form a scatter plot, and analyze the plot to determine the point at which it goes from linear to quadratic. I'll discuss my approach I've tried below, but the problem is there is no real way to do this other than "eyeball it" that I'm able to come up with.

My approach to this was to iteratively compare the slope between the first point and second point, then the first point and third point, etc, and see when this value would start to deviate. Problem with that was this is a  scatter plot, so the slope value between all of the points deviate quite a bit. I then tried to compare the y-values, and see when a square relation might pop up between y_i and y_i+1. That didn't really work out, because the y value of a point in a scatter plot doesn't necessarily speak of its nature. I've also thought about iteratively creating fits to the curve, but I can't see how that would yield any different results from the previous two attempts. Below is my current attempt with the last method described. Avg is the Y-value and P2 is the X-value. tp is the "turning point" which is where the graph goes from linear to quadratic.

```
'Look for turning point where trend becomes nonlinear'
slp(1) = (Avg(2) - Avg(1)) '/ (P2(2) - P2(1))
Dim delta As Variant
ReDim delta(1 To UBound(slp))

For i = 2 To UBound(LP) 'Looks for turning point by comparing current slopes'
    'slp(i) = WorksheetFunction.Slope(P2(i), Avg(i))
    slp(i) = (Avg(i) - Avg(i - 1)) ' / (P2(i) - P2(i - 1))
    delta(i) = slp(i) - slp(i - 1)
Next i
For i = 1 To UBound(delta)
    If delta(i) >= 4000 Then
        tpx(1) = P2(i)
        tpy(1) = Avg(i)
        'tp(1) = slp(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
For i = 1 To UBound(LP) 'Collects points before and after turning point'
    If P2(i) < tpx(1) Then
        x1(i) = P2(i)
        y1(i) = Avg(i)
    ElseIf P2(i) >= tpx(1) Then
        x2(i) = P2(i)
        y2(i) = Avg(i)
    End If
Next i
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlgkW.png)
I've attached a screencap of the plot to give a better idea of the problem. The blue region is the eyeballed linear region, and the orange is the eyeballed quadratic region.

Comment: Your assumption re: a "turning point" between linear and quadratic curves is, IMO, wrong. It is a well know fact that quadratic equations may be approximated by a linear one for relatively small values of X. You would be better off iterating through possible equations (using regression) and choosing the one with the smallest error when compared to the data. If you insist on using a linear equation, you could try to generate equations using linear regression with the first two points, then the first three, and so on in a loop until you reach an error greater than some arbitrary value.

Comment: It's not really an assumption, rather it's a necessary distinction to make for the application of this code. Without going into too much detail, if the plot goes from linear to quadratic it indicates that the object being analyzed is something, and if it doesn't the object is not something - the example plot is a great example of an object that is something. I tried the linear regression approach, and had a hard time defining those arbitrary values hahaha

Comment: How do you determine the jump between the two? Looking at your plot, (i.e. "eyeballing" it) it would not be unreasonable to assign the first orange dot to the linear region, or conversely the last blue dot tot he quadratic one. Can you post sample data and your criteria?

Comment: I have no real criteria other than "just look for when the plot goes from linear to quadratic", and I don't think too much thought was given towards providing mathematical validation as this is only to return a boolean value. I can't post sample data beyond the given plot unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a same data one can run and compare quadratic and linear least square regressions.

The respective root mean square error (RMSE) are different. RMSE(linear) is higher than RMSE(quadratic), but more or less different depending on the scatter and on the difference of shapes.

In case of quadratic shape, figure 1, RMSE(linear) is much higher than RMSE(quadratic) due to the bad fitting of a linear curve to a quadratic curve. The ratio 10 is far to 1.

In case of almost linear shape, figure 2, the quadratic regression leads to a low value of the coefficient c. Even being quadratic, the curve is almost linear. So both RMSE(linear) and RMSE(quadratic) remain on the same order of magnitude. The ratio  is close to 1.

[image]

The ratio between RMSE(linear) and RMSE(quadratic) appears a good indicator of the shape :

- Ratio close to 1 : The shape is said "of linear kind".
- Ratio significantly higher than 1 : The shape is said "of quadratic kind".

One can object that the scatter might make less significant this indicator. That is partly true. The more the scatter is large the less the coefficient c becomes relatively small. But even with an high scatter as on figures 3 and 4 the ratio continue to be significant.

[image]

Again the shape on figure 3 is said "of quadratic kind" and the shape on figure 4 is said "of linear kind".

Nevertheless the ratio (slightly higher than 1) which defines the limit between "of linear kind" and "of quadratic kind" remains subjective (or empirical).

Comment: You are an actual god! I'll try and apply this to my code later today. Thank you!